# 50 Reputation on comments is too much? Add new function to suggest?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, reputation, privileges

I have low reputation as you see. And the problem i see with this is, that when i try to troubleshoot someone's question that requires some active or continuous communication, or a suggestion like "try this if it works", then i probably won't put all of these above into an answer. I'd like the commenting to be lower on reputation to about 10 or 15. Or maybe, Someone could add a function similar to a comment. Called suggestion for instance. Have a comment and a suggestion on 2 different spaces.

Comment: It is a bit of a hassle, but it is a balance with new users as well. I suggest you answer a few questions as you are able (it should not be too difficult to find something you can answer) or ask a few good questions of your own and soon you will have enough rep.

Comment: Strange, question has a downvote and answer has 6 downvotes but comments have 5 upvotes.

Answer (score -6):

I would lower the comment reputation requirement to e.g. 20 and add comments of users below 50 to the "First Post Review" queue. It is usually the emptiest one anyway, so that should work.

Comment: If some queue is empty, I'd prefer to keep it that way.

Comment: too easy to leave spam in comments and asking for a rep of 50 is not really that much.

Comment: Is there a statistic or diagram or something like that available on how many comments are made by users of a reputation score of x per day? That would be interesting to determine whether it is possible or good to add that to a review queue.

Comment: I leave more comments then answers these days. comments to improve questions or answers and sometimes a nudge to get people to read up a bit on a various topic. I have enough rep I and am happy to nudge people and allow them to get credit for their improvements.